# How to update array to database in zend?

Tags: postgresql, zend-framework

I tried update my digit in array to database in zend but i can't 
My code is:

```
$tab = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$varData = array('res' => $tab);
$varWhere = array("id = $idUser");      
$this->objDB->update('table_name', $varData, $varWhere);
```

In database my field "res" is type  integer[].
How can i should do it ?

Comment: conflict with format array from [] on {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done this way. You've got to prepare your $tab array to be ready to insert as a PostgreSQL array type.

For example:

```
$tab = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$tabValue = '{' . implode(',', $tab) . '}';
$varData = array('res' => $tabValue);
$varWhere = array('id = ?' => $idUser);      
$this->objDB->update('table_name', $varData, $varWhere);
```